# In Flask calling cursor.stored_results() throws error AttributeError: 'DictCursor' object has no attribute 'stored_results'

Tags: python, mysql, flask, mysql-python

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, request, jsonify
from flask_mysqldb import MySQL

app = Flask(__name__)


app.config['MYSQL_USER'] = 'root'
app.config['MYSQL_PASSWORD'] = 'password'
app.config['MYSQL_HOST'] = 'localhost'
app.config['MYSQL_DB'] = 'mydb'
app.config['MYSQL_CURSORCLASS'] = 'DictCursor'

mysql = MySQL(app)

@app.route("/user", methods=['GET'])
def fetch_all_user():
    output = []
    try:
        curs = mysql.connection.cursor()
        r = curs.callproc('fetch_all_user')

        # for result in cur.stored_results():
        #   print(result.fetchall())
        print(type(r))
        print(r)
        rs = curs.stored_results()
        print(type(rs))
        print(rs)
        for result in rs:
            print (result.fetchall())

    except mysql.connection.Error as error:
        print("Something went wron: {}".format(error))

    finally:
        curs.close()

    return jsonify({"output":"output"})


if __name__=="__main__":
    app.run(debug=True)
```

print result of type(r) and r :

```
<class 'tuple'>
()
```

```
rs = curs.stored_results()

AttributeError: 'DictCursor' object has no attribute 'stored_results'
```

**PROBLEM COMES IN**

when i call curs.stored_results() it throws error *AttributeError: 'DictCursor' object has no attribute 'stored_results'*. I have made another function which sends post request and insert values into table using stored procedure that function works fine. but I'm having trouble in fetching data.

Answer (score 0):

flask_mysqldb doesn't have stored_results function. You can use like this.

```
curs.callproc('fetch_all_user')
r = curs.fetchall()
```

if you want to use parameters in your procedure

```
args = (parameter1,)
curs.callproc('fetch_all_user',args)
r = curs.fetchall()
```